# Missing characters on a xbox live card

Tags: xbox-network

My dog destroyed my xbox live card and it's missing 2 characters in it. Is there any way, besides just trial and error, to correctly guess some digits/letters ? I really don't want to go through the massive trial and error process of entering all of the different possible combinations.

Comment: If the algorithm for gift cards was known, Microsoft would change it instantly.  I suspect your only recourse is going to be to see if you can return it at the store.

Answer (score 1):

I would contact Microsoft support.  I know I've had iTunes cards where the code got scratched off, and they have a process for identifying the card and sending you the code.  I assume Microsoft can do something similar.

Comment: I thought they had a disclaimer on them, removing liability once the code is sold.

Comment: @Charging They may, but even so, that doesn't mean they won't help you.  It just means you can't sue if they don't.

Answer (score 0):

The only option you have is trial and error, if you want to redeem the code.

Comment: Assuming you won't get banned before you get it right.

Comment: And you probably will..